# Why can't I get my <ng-templates> to display the correct html when I am using a click event on an html element?

Tags: angular, angular9

I have made a calendar to where I want to be able to schedule things when clicked on in each cell. If I have for example an existing "appointment", when clicking on or inside the `<li>` it should popup a dropdown box that says "View appointment."

If I click outside of the already existing appointment within the  element, when clicked on I want it to display a popup dropdown box that displays a different set of menu options such as "Add Time", "View Time", "Add appointment", "View Appointments."

Here is the .html file

```
<ng-container *ngIf="entries.length > 0 || appointments.length > 0 || recurrances.length > 0">
              <tr *ngFor="let w of allDates">
                <td class='days clickable' *ngFor="let d of w" (click)="openMenu($event,d)">
                  <span class="top-left">{{d.getDate()}}</span>
                  <h4 class="center">{{ getHours(d) }}</h4>
                    <ul>
                      <li class="sticky-note" *ngFor="let a of getAppointments(d)" (click)="openMenu2($event,a)">
                        {{a}}
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container *ngIf="entries.length == 0 && appointments.length == 0 && recurrances.length == 0">
              <tr *ngFor="let w of allDates">
                <td class='days' (click)="openMenu($event, d)" *ngFor="let d of w">
                    <span class="top-left">{{d.getDate()}}</span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </ng-container>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<ng-template #userMenu let-e>
  <section class="user-menu">
    <div class="user-menu-item" (click)="showTicket(e)">View Ticket</div>
    <div class="user-menu-item" (click)="addTimeEntry(e)">Add time</div>
    <div class="user-menu-item" (click)="showTimeEntries(e)">View time</div>
    <div class="user-menu-item" (click)="addAppointment(e)">Add appointment</div>
    <div class="user-menu-item" (click)="showAppointmentEntries(e)">View appointments</div>
  </section>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #userMenu2 let-a>
  <section class="user-menu">
    <div class="user-menu-item" (click)="showAppointmentEntry(a)">View appointment</div>
  </section>
</ng-template>
```

With the above html in place, I am only displaying the first `<ng-template>` no matter if I click inside the `<td>` element but outside the `<li>` element, or inside the `<li>` element but not inside the `' element.

So, how can I fix this so that it will display the second `<ng-template>` when I click inside the `<li>` element and only display the first `<ng-template>` when I click outside of the `<li>` element?

Relevant .ts code

```
@ViewChild('userMenu') userMenu: TemplateRef<any>;
@ViewChild('userMenu2') userMenu2: TemplateRef<any>;

openMenu(event: MouseEvent, param: any) { this.popup.open(event,this.userMenu,param,'start','center'); }
openMenu2(event: MouseEvent, appointment: IAppointment) { this.popup.open(event,this.userMenu2,appointment,'start','center'); console.log("click")}
closeMenu() { this.popup.close(); }
```

Comment: could you please create Stackblitz to reproduce the issue

Comment: This is a big application so setting everything up would take awhile. I will see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

Angular is quite powerful framework, based on that I can give you a solution to your issue,

First give a hash reference to the `td` as `#tdElement`,

then use the `(mouseenter)` and `(mouseleave)` events of the `li` to add and remove a class `do-not-click` on `td`

finally handle `td`'s click event based on the added class `do-not-click`

here is a demonstration

```
<td class='days clickable'
    #tdElement 
    *ngFor="let d of w" 
    (click)="tdElement.classList.contains('do-not-click') ? false : openMenu($event,d)">
     <span class="top-left">{{d.getDate()}}</span>
     <h4 class="center">{{ getHours(d) }}</h4>
     <ul>
        <li class="sticky-note" 
            *ngFor="let a of getAppointments(d)"
            (mouseenter)="tdElement.classList.add('do-not-click')" 
            (mouseleave)="tdElement.classList.remove('do-not-click')"
            (click)="openMenu2($event,a)">
          {{a}}
        </li>
     </ul>
 </td>
```